# The javascript engine of htmlunit can't load the generated page with these settings

Tags: java, htmlunit, javascript-engine

I am trying to get content of script-generated web page but unfortunately `HtmlUnit` doesn't seem to work properly. I think the problem is with the class trying to wrap the script.

Snippet of code:

```
    LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log","org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.client").setLevel(Level.OFF);
 
    String url = "https://db.pokemongohub.net/pokemon/379";
    System.out.println("Loading page now-----------------------------------------------: "+url);
    
    // HtmlUnit 模拟浏览器
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);           
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);                    
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);   
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10 * 1000);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30 * 1000);
    HtmlPage page;
    try {
        page = webClient.getPage(url);
        String pageAsXml = page.asXml();
        System.out.println(pageAsXml);
        
        // Jsoup解析处理
        //org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(pageAsXml, "https://db.pokemongohub.net/pokemon/379");  
        //System.out.println(doc.toString());
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is the console output:

```
Loading page now-----------------------------------------------: https://db.pokemongohub.net/pokemon/379
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html lang="en" data-theme="dark">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#09c077"/>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/images/icons/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/images/icons/favicon-32x32.png"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/images/icons/favicon-16x16.png"/>
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/images/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#09c077"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.google-analytics.com" crossorigin=""/>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#09c077"/>
    <title>
      GO Hub Database: the largest and most accurate Pokemon GO database on the planet
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,viewport-fit=cover"/>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#09c077"/>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="idfhZSA58FPaLHi77oghYS1uGEB1jZm4nCuiSxKXgK8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="The largest and most accurate Pokemon GO database in the world."/>
    <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.6feb70c7.js">
    </script>
    <link href="/static/css/main.cf200460.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script async="" src="/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js">
    </script>
    <style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiPaper">
      
.MuiPaper-root {
  color: #fff;
  transition: box-shadow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  background-color: #424242;
}
.MuiPaper-rounded {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.MuiPaper-outlined {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation0 {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.MuiPaper-elevation1 {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation2 {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation3 {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 3px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation4 {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation5 {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation6 {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation7 {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 7px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 2px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation8 {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation9 {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 9px 12px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 3px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation10 {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 10px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 4px 18px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation11 {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 7px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 11px 15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 4px 20px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation12 {
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 12px 17px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation13 {
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 13px 19px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 24px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation14 {
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 14px 21px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 26px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation15 {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 9px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 15px 22px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 28px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation16 {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 16px 24px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 30px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation17 {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 11px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 17px 26px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 32px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation18 {
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 11px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 18px 28px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 7px 34px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation19 {
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 12px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 19px 29px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 7px 36px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation20 {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 20px 31px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 38px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation21 {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 21px 33px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 40px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation22 {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 22px 35px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 42px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation23 {
  box-shadow: 0px 11px 14px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 23px 36px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 9px 44px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.MuiPaper-elevation24 {
  box-shadow: 0px 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

    </style>
    <style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiDrawer">
      
.MuiDrawer-docked {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.MuiDrawer-paper {
  top: 0;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  outline: 0;
  z-index: 1200;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorLeft {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}
.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorRight {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorTop {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorBottom {
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorDockedLeft {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}
.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorDockedTop {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}
.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorDockedRight {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}
.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorDockedBottom {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

    </style>
    <style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiAppBar">
      
.MuiAppBar-root {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1100;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.MuiAppBar-positionFixed {
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
@media print {
  .MuiAppBar-positionFixed {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
.MuiAppBar-positionAbsolute {
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.MuiAppBar-positionSticky {
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  position: sticky;
}
.MuiAppBar-positionStatic {
  position: static;
}
.MuiAppBar-positionRelative {
  position: relative;
}
.MuiAppBar-colorDefault {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #212121;
}
.MuiAppBar-colorPrimary {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  background-color: #09c077;
}
.MuiAppBar-colorSecondary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f50057;
}
.MuiAppBar-colorInherit {
  color: inherit;
}
.MuiAppBar-colorTransparent {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
}

    </style>
    <style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiToolbar">
      
.MuiToolbar-root {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}
.MuiToolbar-gutters {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
@media (min-width:600px) {
  .MuiToolbar-gutters {
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
  }
}
.MuiToolbar-regular {
  min-height: 56px;
}
@media (min-width:0px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .MuiToolbar-regular {
    min-height: 48px;
  }
}
@media (min-width:600px) {
  .MuiToolbar-regular {
    min-height: 64px;
  }
}
.MuiToolbar-dense {
  min-height: 48px;
}

    </style>
    <style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiTouchRipple">
      
.MuiTouchRipple-root {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: inherit;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.MuiTouchRipple-ripple {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.MuiTouchRipple-rippleVisible {
  opacity: 0.3;
  animation: MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-enter 550ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.MuiTouchRipple-ripplePulsate {
  animation-duration: 200ms;
}
.MuiTouchRipple-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: currentColor;
}
.MuiTouchRipple-childLeaving {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-exit 550ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
.MuiTouchRipple-childPulsate {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-pulsate 2500ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 200ms infinite;
}
@keyframes MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.1;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.3;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-exit {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes MuiTouchRipple-keyframes-pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.92);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

    </style>
    <style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiButtonBase">
      
.MuiButtonBase-root {
  color: inherit;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.MuiButtonBase-root::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
}
.MuiButtonBase-root.Mui-disabled {
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
@media print {
  .MuiButtonBase-root {
    color-adjust: exact;
  }
}

    </style>
    <style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiIconButton">
      
.MuiIconButton-root {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow: visible;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.MuiIconButton-root:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}
.MuiIconButton-root.Mui-disabled {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  background-color: transparent;
}
@media (hover: none) {
  .MuiIconButton-root:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
.MuiIconButton-edgeStart {
  margin-left: -12px;
}
.MuiIconButton-sizeSmall.MuiIconButton-edgeStart {
  margin-left: -3px;
}
.MuiIconButton-edgeEnd {
  margin-right: -12px;
}
.MuiIconButton-sizeSmall.MuiIconButton-edgeEnd {
  margin-right: -3px;
}
.MuiIconButton-colorInherit {
  color: inherit;
}
.MuiIconButton-colorPrimary {
  color: #09c077;
}
.MuiIconButton-colorPrimary:hover {
  background-color: rgba(9, 192, 119, 0.08);
}
@media (hover: none) {
  .MuiIconButton-colorPrimary:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
.MuiIconButton-colorSecondary {
  color: #f50057;
}
.MuiIconButton-colorSecondary:hover {
  background-color: rgba(245, 0, 87, 0.08);
}
@media (hover: none) {
  .MuiIconButton-colorSecondary:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
.MuiIconButton-sizeSmall {
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
.MuiIconButton-label {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: inherit;
  justify-content: inherit;
}

    </style>
    <style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiSvgIcon">
      
.MuiSvgIcon-root {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  user-select: none;
}
.MuiSvgIcon-colorPrimary {
  color: #09c077;
}
.MuiSvgIcon-colorSecondary {
  color: #f50057;
}
.MuiSvgIcon-colorAction {
  color: #fff;
}
.MuiSvgIcon-colorError {
  color: #f44336;
}
.MuiSvgIcon-colorDisabled {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeInherit {
  font-size: inherit;
}
.MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeSmall {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeLarge {
  font-size: 2.1875rem;
}

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/396.7ab6dd82.chunk.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="AxujKG9INjsZ8/gUq8+dTruNvk7RjZQ1oFhhgQbcTJKDnZfbzSTE81wvC2Hzaf3TW4avA76LTZEMdiedF1vIbA4AAABueyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2ltYXNkay5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiVHJ1c3RUb2tlbnMiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE2NTI3NzQ0MDAsImlzVGhpcmRQYXJ0eSI6dHJ1ZX0="/>
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="Azuce85ORtSnWe1MZDTv68qpaW3iHyfL9YbLRy0cwcCZwVnePnOmkUJlG8HGikmOwhZU22dElCcfrfX2HhrBPAkAAAB7eyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2RvdWJsZWNsaWNrLm5ldDo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiVHJ1c3RUb2tlbnMiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE2NTI3NzQ0MDAsImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlLCJpc1RoaXJkUGFydHkiOnRydWV9"/>
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="A16nvcdeoOAqrJcmjLRpl1I6f3McDD8EfofAYTt/P/H4/AWwB99nxiPp6kA0fXoiZav908Z8etuL16laFPUdfQsAAACBeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZXRhZ3NlcnZpY2VzLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiVHJ1c3RUb2tlbnMiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE2NTI3NzQ0MDAsImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlLCJpc1RoaXJkUGFydHkiOnRydWV9"/>
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="AxBHdr0J44vFBQtZUqX9sjiqf5yWZ/OcHRcRMN3H9TH+t90V/j3ENW6C8+igBZFXMJ7G3Pr8Dd13632aLng42wgAAACBeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZXN5bmRpY2F0aW9uLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiVHJ1c3RUb2tlbnMiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE2NTI3NzQ0MDAsImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlLCJpc1RoaXJkUGFydHkiOnRydWV9"/>
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="A88BWHFjcawUfKU3lIejLoryXoyjooBXLgWmGh+hNcqMK44cugvsI5YZbNarYvi3roc1fYbHA1AVbhAtuHZflgEAAAB2eyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZS5jb206NDQzIiwiZmVhdHVyZSI6IlRydXN0VG9rZW5zIiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNjUyNzc0NDAwLCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZSwiaXNUaGlyZFBhcnR5Ijp0cnVlfQ=="/>
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="A8FHS1NmdCwGqD9DwOicnHHY+y27kdWfxKa0YHSGDfv0CSpDKRHTQdQmZVPDUdaFWUsxdgVxlwAd6o+dhJykPA0AAACWeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2RvdWJsZWNsaWNrLm5ldDo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiQ29udmVyc2lvbk1lYXN1cmVtZW50IiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNjQzMTU1MTk5LCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZSwiaXNUaGlyZFBhcnR5Ijp0cnVlLCJ1c2FnZSI6InN1YnNldCJ9"/>
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="A8zdXi6dr1hwXEUjQrYiyYQGlU3557y5QWDnN0Lwgj9ePt66XMEvNkVWOEOWPd7TP9sBQ25X0Q15Lr1Nn4oGFQkAAACceyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZXN5bmRpY2F0aW9uLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiQ29udmVyc2lvbk1lYXN1cmVtZW50IiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNjQzMTU1MTk5LCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZSwiaXNUaGlyZFBhcnR5Ijp0cnVlLCJ1c2FnZSI6InN1YnNldCJ9"/>
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="A4/Htern2udN9w3yJK9QgWQxQFruxOXsXL7cW60DyCl0EZFGCSme/J33Q/WzF7bBkVvhEWDlcBiUyZaim5CpFQwAAACceyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZXRhZ3NlcnZpY2VzLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiQ29udmVyc2lvbk1lYXN1cmVtZW50IiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNjQzMTU1MTk5LCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZSwiaXNUaGlyZFBhcnR5Ijp0cnVlLCJ1c2FnZSI6InN1YnNldCJ9"/>
  </head>
  <body class="go-hub-db--loaded">
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="go-hub-db-app" style="display: none !important;">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="go-hub-header">
            <header class="MuiPaper-root MuiAppBar-root MuiAppBar-positionStatic MuiAppBar-colorPrimary global-header MuiPaper-elevation4">
              <div class="MuiToolbar-root MuiToolbar-regular menu-toolbar MuiToolbar-gutters">
                <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root mobile-menu-opener" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Menu">
                  <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                    <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewbox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                      <path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"/>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root">
                  </span>
                </button>
                <a href="/">
                  <img src="/images/go-hub-logo.svg" alt="Pokemon GO database, Pokemon stats and wiki"/>
                </a>
                <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root search-opener" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Search">
                  <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                    <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewbox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                      <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root">
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </header>
            <div class="MuiDrawer-root MuiDrawer-docked">
              <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiDrawer-paper MuiDrawer-paperAnchorLeft MuiDrawer-paperAnchorDockedLeft MuiPaper-elevation0">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui--loading">
        <div style="opacity: 1.0; transition-delay: 100ms; webkit-transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 100ms; transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 100ms;">
          <svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewbox="0 0 82.3 82.3" enable-background="new 0 0 82.3 82.3" xml:space="preserve" class="spinner">
            <g>
              <g>
                <path fill="#D1D3D4" d="M48.3,0.7C37.1-1.3,26.8,1,17.5,7.5C8.3,14,2.6,22.8,0.7,34c-1.8,9.9-0.2,19.1,4.7,27.5l17.2-12 c-3.9-8.7-1.2-19.3,6.9-25s19-4.6,25.8,2.1l17.2-12C66.2,7,58.2,2.4,48.3,0.7z M59.7,32.8c3.9,8.7,1.2,19.3-6.9,25 s-19,4.6-25.8-2.1l-17.2,12C16,75.2,24.1,79.8,34,81.6c11.2,2,21.4-0.3,30.7-6.7c9.3-6.5,14.9-15.3,16.9-26.5 c1.8-9.9,0.2-19.1-4.7-27.5L59.7,32.8z"/>
              </g>
              <g>
                <ellipse transform="matrix(0.8192 -0.5736 0.5736 0.8192 -16.149 31.0404)" fill="#D1D3D4" cx="41.1" cy="41.1" rx="13.8" ry="13.8"/>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
          <span class="loading-message">
            Doubling Murkrow spawns...
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="/images/pokeball-gray.svg" class="loader"/>
    <style>
      .loader{max-width:120px;position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;margin-left:-60px;margin-top:-60px;z-index:-1;animation:pokeball-spin 1s linear infinite}@keyframes pokeball-spin{100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}.go-hub-db--loaded .loader{display:none}
    </style>
    <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-80874150-4">
    </script>
    <script>
//<![CDATA[
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)}window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[],gtag("js",new Date),gtag("config","UA-80874150-4")
//]]>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function(){window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'6f0106df1e4283a3',m:'Qt_GQK5KARH8DdQ1Js9Ky19.2OfYiLdvUV.4CMUe4Ew-1647974123-0-AZs26Z98OFU0ksggOYox8AUyBwshufDnlT3EHWAuqN9VDmbfAByxNs7YWwrkcIhf2AOlQGEy4Vjfw4B8tRE9Kg71UEKwrvJLCDJeDsCvHoZSvZho9kVcecHOXPP1rhq3ew==',s:[0x3c817a274e,0x98c5e8caaf],}})();
//]]>
    </script>
  </body>
  <iframe id="google_esf" name="google_esf" src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/html/r20220317/r20190131/zrt_lookup.html" style="display: none;">
  </iframe>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but when i try to reproduce i always get an 403 error. What HtmlUnit version do you use?

Btw: you have to call webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30 * 1000); AFTER page = webClient.getPage(url);

Comment: htmlunit-2.60.0.
Yes, I know. I've tried also to put if after.

Comment: Please open an issue on github - htmlunit and let us discuss this there.

Comment: Have done another debug session,looks like this page is hosted/protected via Cloudflare and HtmlUnit does not pass the check done.

Comment: I see. So there is nothing I can do about it, right?

Comment: I fear not, at the moment i have no idea and no time to dig deeper into this. Sorry